# I am Using Windows server 2008 R2. I Want to Install OS in The Virtual Machines through C# code.Is there any solution for that?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I am using the hyper v role of windows server 2008 R2. I want to install OS in the virtual machine through C# code.

Also if there is an existing VHD of other VM can I able to link that VHD to a new VM with C# code.
Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ah. No. You can not never ever install an OS from C# code, you know. How would you do that on a physical server?

There are some ways to autoamte the setup process. They are windows integrated (unattended install) and a prepared image could possibly use a .NET program to pull an answer file automatically, but that is something different than you asked for.

> can I able to link that VHD to a new
>   VM with C# code

All the configuration you can easily do from any windows integrated language (which includes any .net language). Hyper-v, being a windows system feature, is fully exposed through WMI.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/benp/archive/2008/08/11/scripting-hyper-v-with-wmi-and-powershell-part-1-introduction-querying-state.aspx

has some starts for using PowerShell, the same principles apply for any WMI capable language.

Answer (score 1):

C# is just a language, and much like any other.  The question you're asking has little to do with language.

If you're asking if you can programmatically manipulate a VM under Hyper-V, the answer is yes.  Hyper-V is entirely managed through WMI interfaces, as defined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136992(VS.85).aspx

You can interact with that in C#, using the .Net WMI classes, or you can (probably more easily) drive PowerShell cmdlets with your C# code.  Whichever you're more comfortable with, they'll be more similar than different, as they both resolve down to .Net classes.